# How to properly read a local Json file and assign to a struct?

Tags: swift

For some reason I just can't get this to work. example of json info:

```
{
"#": 1,
"Country": "Afghanistan",
"Population\n(2020)": 38928346,
"Land Area\n(Km²)": 652860,
"Density\n(P/Km²)": 60,
"FACTS": "The 1 country on the alphabetical list is: Afghanistan"
```

the struct I have set up:

```
struct Country: Codable {
var aNumber: Int
var cName: String
var population: Int
var landArea: Int
var density: Int
var facts: String
}
struct Countries: Codable {
    var results: [Country]
}
```

how do I properly read the json file to assign it to the struct?

the only thing that I have gotten close to work is this:

```
private func readJson() {
        do {
            if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "csvjson", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let object = json as? [String: Any] {
                    // json is a dictionary
                    print("success")
                } else if let object = json as? [Any] {
                    // json is an array - THIS PART WORKS
                    dataAtt = object
                } else {
                    print("JSON is invalid")
                }
            } else {
                print("no file")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

which only get it to type Any, but I can't get that to work with the structs or assign it in any way

Comment: Without knowing the beginning of the JSON the question cannot be answered seriously. And why do you adopt `Codable` but don't use the protocol?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, and this is the best way to load the local json file.

1. Your model will be like this, and this is a sample model created as per the sample json given in your question.

> ```
> struct Country: Codable {
>
>   let empty: Int
>   let country: String
>   let population2020, landAreaKM, densityPKM: Int
>   let facts: String
>
>   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
>     case empty = "#"
>     case country = "Country"
>     case population2020 = "Population\n(2020)"
>     case landAreaKM = "Land Area\n(Km²)"
>     case densityPKM = "Density\n(P/Km²)"
>     case facts = "FACTS"
>   }
> }
>
> typealias Countries = [Country]
> ```

2. You can load the json as follows

Code:

```
func loadCountries(_ filename: String) ->Countries {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(Countries.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(Countries.self):\n\(error)")
    } }
```

Keep codinging....